# Is it possible to encrypt full volumes post-boot?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, encryption, kali-linux

I have a triple boot system with Windows 7 Ultimate, Kali Linux, and Ubuntu Linux. My bootloader is Grub2. Initially, I wanted full disk encryption covering all three installations but I've found that to be a headache. Is it possible to have on-the-fly encryption of each of the system volumes or partitions post boot? I don't mind having to enter the password each time I go into a different OS and I realize that this won't be as secure as full disk encryption. The reality is that I just need to protect against the average user (or mis-user) and not the FBI.

Is there one program that can do this for both Windows and Linux? How? Thanks.

Comment: Yes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software